# Issues when trying to OCR PDFs using .NET/C#

Tags: c#, pdf, ocr

1. Old versions of Adobe PDF used to distinguish Searchable PDF/Image PDF in one particular way.  In Searchable PDF, you can select the text and image only pdf when you try to select a gray text box will come (no text selected).  This was the thumb rule earlier.  But now with Adobe DC, this has changed.  Adobe DC, allows you to select the text even for image pdf/s (non-searchable pdf’s).  But if you try to copy and paste, it does not paste what you copied, you get some special characters.  Any idea why Adobe DC does it?  What is the thumb rule now to find out what is searchable pdf and what is image pdf (non-ocr pdf)?
2. Some of non-OCR pdf documents, when try to do OCR, are getting “renderable text” error and OCR is failed for those page.  What is the best way to eliminate this “This page contains renderable text” error and what is the best way to OCR such pages.
3. How to programmatically OCR pdf document in C#?  If this takes more time, what are the ways to handle session timeouts?  Anyway to do OCR in the back-ground and send to the user at the end (idea is to not holding the user in the front-end and still some way to deliver the created file to the submitter once the process is done).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the PDF page contains an image without text, the only way to get text from it is to use OCR. Both Adobe Acrobat DC and some earlier versions of Acrobat have OCR features, but as far as I know, you can only OCR one or more pages, not a small selection.
   This means if you have an image and Acrobat allows you to select text off of it without explicitly running OCR, most probably the file already contains image-over-text or hidden text over the image. If the text is garbled when you copy and paste it, it's probably how it was stored when it was OCR'd and saved. This could have happened because the text quality was not good enough for OCR, or the software used to perform OCR was of low quality and got the characters incorrectly.
2. If you try to OCR and get "page contains renderable text" error, this means the file already contains text. Again, the text could be hidden, but it's there. The following article explains more about this:
   https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/error-could-perform-recognition-acrobat.html
3. There are several SDKs that support opening and OCRing PDF files using C#. This area of StackOverflow is not the place to ask for recommendations. Please try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead.